# Storing OpenSSL BIGNUM operation result

Tags: openssl, bignum

OpenSSL functions over `BIGNUM`s take as first argument the variable where the result will be stored, like 
`int BN_add(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b);`, which calculates `r=a+b`;
Is it safe the use`a` in the following statement, or should I declare a new variable to hold the result?

```
BN_add(a, a, b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe, you can look-up examples in `crypto/bn/bntest.c`. There you can find code like:

```
    BN_add(&c, &c, &b);
    BN_sub(&c, &c, &a);
```

Furthermore, according to https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_add.html :

> BN_add() adds a and b and places the result in r (r=a+b). r may be the
>   same BIGNUM as a or b.